# Ubuntu Minimal Version Install

Tags: versions, ubuntu-minimal

Can anyone provide a valid link or website to download a minimal version of Ubuntu?

Comment: There is no such thing. Normal download as an option to install a basic Ubuntu.

Comment: There was *never* an official minimal ISO, it was produced only as a *side effect* of the building of the Debian Installer ISOs, which are no longer produced (The *debian installer* was replaced by `subiquity`).  Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD which states "*Canonical and the Ubuntu project never officially supported the mini.iso ; it was produced as a by-product of building the debian-installer. As the Ubuntu Server image now uses subiquity, the build process that built mini.iso is no longer used, thus why this installation media is now old.*"

Comment: You weren't very specific, some ISOs offer a *minimal* install option, but not all do.  You gave no clues as to what Ubuntu product, which release, and which ISO (some have multiple ISOs including *alternate* with different options)... but not all have a *minimal install* option available.

Answer (score 1):

The only supported Ubuntu "Minimal" install is an option on the normal installer. It takes slightly *longer* than a normal install.

There are several other ways that folks roll their own Minimal installs. These are not recommended for beginners, and problems with those highly-customized systems are rarely solved here.

Debian, our good friend, DOES have a real and supported [Minimally-sized installer (netinst)](https://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/) that you can build up a Minimal system from. Netinst is great in a VM for folks who want to learn, test, and play with respins. Of course, problems with Debian systems are off-topic here.

- Generally, A VM is recommended over trying netinst on bare metal. Minimal systems tend to encounter problems (often missing packages) that get them wiped and reinstalled.

For Advanced Ubuntu Users who like a Minimal challenge, [Ubuntu Base](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/releases/) is waiting for you. As Advanced users, you don't need instructions here. You know where to find the docs.